# SASS source maps Chrome not reloading CSS correctly

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I am trying to get SASS source maps and the auto reloading/saving to disk to work. I have everything set up with `grunt-contrib-sass` and watch task to recompile my `.scss` on changes, and my source maps are working correctly in Chrome in the way that I can edit the SASS and it gets saved to disk. My problem is that when I edit the SASS, the page reloads as if there is no CSS at all. If I then reload the page, my applied changes are indeed there.

Any idea why this happens?

Before sass-change in dev tools:http://cl.ly/image/1R2o2I113H3y
After: http://cl.ly/image/1m0V3b0J420X

I am using Google Canary 33.0.1738.0

Comment: Hard to know whats up from the info given.  Inspect the page with the dev tools after it reloads the new CSS.  What's in the `style` or `link` tags? Ae they even present? Do they have text of some kind of error? Inspect the page to figure out what's preventing the reloaded styles from applying, and troubleshoot from there.

Comment: If I inspect the DOM after having made a change, the link tag to my .css file is there, and when I highlight the link-tag (just clicking on it) in the DOM-tree, I can see my styles again however the sourcemapping stops working, i.e. the edits I make in dev tools only affect the .css file.

Comment: "edits I make in dev tools only affect the .css file" Edits in the dev tools don't actually edit any files.  It's just a way to preview potential edits.  Your browser doesn't have write permission to the those files.  Source maps allow you to see where things map to your own source, but it doesn't ket you edit that source.

Comment: You can, actually :) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6qe_kVaBpg around 5:30

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what is causing it but I have found a nice extension as a work around for something like that.  I started useing it becuase I didn't want to reload the entire page every time I made a style update.  There is an option under css to reload linked style sheets. [Web Developer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm)